# Tool to mount a zip/rar/* archive as a Win drive and be able to read/write as a normal device?

Tags: windows, mount, zip, rar, virtual-drive

I'm looking for some tool that, given a zip/rar/tar/* archive file, mounts it as a new Windows drive. Some tools are WinMount or WinArchive, but I need one that allows me to write/create/delete files as well as read. That is, just as if it were a USB stick or something like that. The file doesn't need to be compressed, just archived is fine.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if such software exists, but for must compression and archiving methods; removing or changing any part of any file will take at least as long as creating a new archive from scratch.

Comment: It doesn't need to be compressed, just archived is fine.

Comment: Could you use a virtual disk, for example a VHD ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format) )? Should be supported natively in windows 7.

Comment: Yes! didn't know these were supported natively by Windows 7. The problem was having to synchronize tens of thousands of files between machines..so I figured having them in a single file would be easier. Thank you!

Comment: @Eroen Still, if there was a way of doing this with zip, rar, tar or whatever, it'd be great in terms of portability and ease of use.

Comment: See [unix.SE:168807](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168807) for a similar question for Linux.

Comment: @caerolus it would be an extreme PITA to use those **compressed** formats as "disk clones". Tarballs are already kind of better then, but since they lack indexing it's still sub-bar for this use-case.

Answer (score 12):

Try [Pismo File Mount](http://www.pismotechnic.com/pfm/). Its freeware, supports zip, and ISO, but not .rar

Comment: Apparently Prismo can mount 7zip only if it is LZMA? The 'WinArchiver' mentioned by @zackrspv on the other hand seems to support any 7z format (?).

Answer (score 5):

There are a few utilties out there that can do this, but I use this one:

[Win Archiver Virtual Drive](http://www.winarchiver.com/virtual-drive.htm)

Essentially, you can mount any supported type of archive (zip, rar, 7z, iso, etc), to any # of drives you want, and they act just like regular drive.

Quite useful:

[image: Win Archive Virtual Drive]

The image above shows drive K -> O; drive K is actually a mounted RAR file for a .NET project :)

Comment: doesn't seem to support write operations.

Comment: @Quonux that would be almost impossible in general case. It's very hard to update archive contents without massive writing overhead other than to append new files.

Comment: I would argue that it depends on the compressor and its format. It works fine under certain assumptions. One industry case where a online(chunked) compression works is in the Oracle database - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/compression/advanced-compression-wp-12c-1896128.pdf